# How can i use Jupyter Notebook properly when my datas are in a folder on the desktop?

Tags: python-3.x, jupyter-notebook, anaconda, socketserver

i have socketserver code in python. when i use jupyter notebook on the desktop folder(C:\Users\khayy\Desktop\FIT) it does not run. but when i launch it on usser (C:\Users\khayy)
it runs properly.
what is wrong with my desktop

i tried launch and run jupyter notebook but it does not work when i change C:\Users\khayy  to C:\Users\khayy\Desktop\FIT. i use windows 11, python 3.11.5 and jupyter notebook 7.0.6

My code is:

```
import socket, numpy as np
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
import pandas as pd
import sqlite3
from io import StringIO
from m5m10controler104 import *
import csv
from functionsif import *

firstmsg = ""
firstmsg = StringIO(firstmsg)
mergeddf=pd.DataFrame()
global factorglist
global factorrlist
factorglist=[0]
factorrlist=[0]

class socketserver:
    def __init__(self, address='', port=9090):
        self.sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        self.address = address
        self.port = port
        self.sock.bind((self.address, self.port))
        self.cummdata = ''

    def recvmsg(self):
        self.sock.listen(1)
        self.conn, self.addr = self.sock.accept()
        print('connected to', self.addr)
        self.cummdata = ''

        while True:
            data = self.conn.recv(100000)
            self.cummdata += data.decode("utf-8")
            if not data:
                break
            mainsignal = sendsignal(self.cummdata)
            print(mainsignal)
            self.conn.send(bytes(mainsignal, "utf-8"))

            return self.cummdata

    def __del__(self):
        self.sock.close()


def sendsignal(msg=''):
    ticks = StringIO(msg)
    df = pd.read_csv(ticks, index_col=False, names=["DateTime", "Open", "High",
                       "Low", "Close","RSI","MACD1","MACD2",  "TimeFrame", "Symbol_Name"])
    df["DateTime"] = pd.to_datetime(df["DateTime"])
    global mergeddf
    global mergeddfm1
    global mergeddfm5
    global mergeddfm10
    global factorg
    global factorr
    global factorglist
    global factorrlist
    global position
    factorg=''
    factorr=''
    position=''

    mergeddf=pd.concat([mergeddf, df]).drop_duplicates().reset_index(drop=True)
    mergeddfgrouped = mergeddf.groupby(mergeddf['TimeFrame'])
    mergeddfm1 = mergeddfgrouped.get_group("M1")
    mergeddfm5 = mergeddfgrouped.get_group("M5")
    mergeddfm10 = mergeddfgrouped.get_group("M10")
    print(mergeddfm5.tail(2))
    print(mergeddfm10.tail(2))
    print(mergeddfm1.tail(3))

    def write_to_csv(listt):
        with open('log.csv', 'a') as f:
            writer = csv.writer(f)
            writer.writerow(listt)
            

    try:
    if (mergeddfm1['Open'].iloc[-1]<=mergeddfm1['Close'].iloc[-1]):
        [factorg,factorglist]=m1m5m10controlercodeg(mergeddfm1,...
        mergeddfm5,mergeddfm10,factorg,factorglist)
        if (factorg==2):
            position='buy'
        elif (factorg==1):
            position='sell'

        lst=[mergeddfm1['DateTime'].iloc[-1],factorg,factorrlist[-1],'G',position]
        write_to_csv(lst)

    elif (mergeddfm1['Open'].iloc[-1]>mergeddfm1['Close'].iloc[-1]):
        [factorr,factorrlist]=m1m5m10controlercoder(mergeddfm1,
         mergeddfm5,mergeddfm10,factorr,factorrlist)

        if (factorr==1):
            position='sell'
        elif (factorr==2):
            position='buy'

        lst=[mergeddfm1['DateTime'].iloc[-1],factorr,factorglist[-1],'R',position]
        write_to_csv(lst)
    except:
        print(f'An Error Occured At {(mergeddfm1["DateTime"].iloc[-1])}')
        pass

    print(f'position==========={position}')  
    position=position
    positions=[[position,"0","0","EURUSD"]]
    position=''


    signal = ""

    if len(positions[0][0])>0:      
        for i in range(len(positions)):
            signal = signal + positions[i][0] + " " + positions[i][1] + " " + 
                 positions[i][2] + " " + positions[i][3] + " "
    else:
        signal=""
    return signal



serv = socketserver('127.0.0.1', 9090)

while True:
    msg = serv.recvmsg()
```

Comment: When you say it "does not run", do you get any error message? If you do, could you add it to your question, please.